# Which BPMN gateway do I have to use?

Tags: bpmn

I'm building this BPMN in which a user has to fill 6 forms (do 6 tasks). After he's completed all 6 he should get some results, but if any of those tasks are missing, then we do not have the results.

Which gateway should I use? The one I thought suited the most was the inclusive gateway, but all 6 tasks can be completed in any order.

Should I use a complex gateway and just describe the process? Or the parallel gateway works just fine

Answer (score 0):

If exactly 6 tasks have to be performed in any desired order, and the flow shall not continue before all 6 are completed,  the simplest would be to use a [**parallel gateway**](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/modeler/bpmn/parallel-gateways/):

[image]

As soon as a token arrives at the first gate, a token is send on every outgoing flow, which activates each of the tasks.  The gate at the left will generate a token to continue the flow once every task is complete and passed its token to the gate.

The complex gateway could also address your needs, since it allows complex conditions on the incoming and outgoing flows, including with multiple tokens on multiple branch.  This would be necessary for example if 5 out of 6 tasks would have to be completed, or if you only want some combinations of completed tasks to continue the flow.  But it seems overkill for your problem.

The inclusive gateway is not a solution for your needs, since it only allows one of the outgoing branch to be activated.